# How to store the output of AWK command in a separate directory?

Tags: shell, unix

I have splited a file into multiple text files using below command -

awk '{print $2 > $1"_npsc.txt"}' complete.txt

I want to store all the output generated text files to another directory. How I can achieve this ? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
awk '{print $2 > "path/to/directory"$1"_npsc.txt"}' complete.txt
```

Just make sure that you create the director first (and replace path/to/directory with a the path that you like)